# why is it that my object is not declared in the scope?

Tags: c++

Im having the typical c++ error of "x" is not declared in this scope.

This is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include "funciones.h"

using namespace std;


class Materia{

private:
    int nroMateria;
    char nombreMateria[40];
    int cantAlumnos;
    int cantDocentes;

public:

    void Cargar(){

        int nro;

        cout<<"NUMERO DE MATERIA: ";
        cin>>nro;
        setNroMateria(nro);
        cout<<"NOMBRE DE MATERIA: ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(nombreMateria,35);
        cout<<"CANTIDAD DE ALUMNOS: ";
        cin>>cantAlumnos;
        cout<<"CANTIDAD DE DOCENTES: ";
        cin>>cantDocentes;        
        
    }

    void Mostrar();


    void setNroMateria(int nm){if(nm>0)nroMateria=nm;}
    void setNombreMateria(const char *nm){strcpy(nombreMateria,nm);}
    int getNroMateria(){return nroMateria;}
    char *getNombreMateria(){return nombreMateria;}


};        
void Materia::Mostrar(){

        cout<<"NUMERO DE MATERIA: ";
        cout<<nroMateria<<endl;
        cout<<"NOMBRE DE MATERIA: ";
        cout<<nombreMateria<<endl;
        cout<<"CANTIDAD DE ALUMNOS: ";
        cout<<cantAlumnos<<endl;
        cout<<"CANTIDAD DE DOCENTES: ";
        cout<<cantDocentes<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<endl;    
    
}



int main(){


    int opc;


    while(true){
        system("cls");
        cout<<"MENU ARTICULOS: "<<endl;
        cout<<"1. CARGAR MATERIAS: "<<endl;
        cout<<"2. MOSTRAR MATERIAS: "<<endl;
        cout<<"0. SALIR DEL PROGRAMA: "<<endl;
        cout<<"SELECCIONE UNA OPCCION: "<<endl;
        cin>>opc;
        system("cls");
        switch(opc){
        case 1:
            CargarMateria();
            break;
        case 2:
            MostrarMateria();
            break;

        case 0:
            return 0;
            break;

        }
        system("pause");
    }


return 0;
}
```

And i have my class Materia with all its properties and methods. And then i have a menu to trigger different options.

This is my funciones.h file:

```
void CargarMateria();
void MostrarMateria();

bool grabarEnDisco(Materia);

void CargarMateria(){


    Materia obj;

    obj.Cargar();

    if(grabarEnDisco(obj)==true){
        cout<<"REGISTRO AGREGADO";
    }else {


        cout<<"NO SE PUDO AGREGAR EL REGISTRO";

    }

    cout<<endl;

}


void MostrarMateria(){

    FILE *pMateria;
    Materia obj;

    pMateria = fopen("materias.dat", "rb");

    ///wb abre el archivo en modo escritura -> SIEMPRE CREA UN ARCHIVO VACIO
    ///ab abre el archivo y permite que se le agreguen registros.
    ///rb abre el archivo y permite leer los registros. Si no existe da error.

    if(pMateria == NULL){
        cout<<"ERROR DE ARCHIVO";
        return;
    }

    fread(&obj,sizeof(Materia),1,pMateria);
    fclose(pMateria);
    obj.Mostrar();       
    

}


bool grabarEnDisco(Materia obj){

    FILE *pMateria;

    pMateria = fopen("materias.dat", "wb");

    ///wb abre el archivo en modo escritura -> SIEMPRE CREA UN ARCHIVO VACIO
    ///ab abre el archivo y permite que se le agreguen registros.
    ///rb abre el archivo y permite leer los registros. Si no existe da error.

    if(pMateria == NULL){
        cout<<"ERROR DE ARCHIVO";
        return false;
    }

    fwrite(&obj,sizeof(Materia),1,pMateria);
    fclose(pMateria);
    return true;


}
#endif // FUNCIONES_H_INCLUDED
```

And above i have a few functions to generate write and read a file. But where i first have a prototype function:

```
bool grabarEnDisco(Materia);
```

I get

```
'Materia' was not declared in this scope
```

Any clue way this is happening?

Comment: Because `functiones.h` is read before `class Materia` appears `main.cpp`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews but im using c file system

Comment: The `fopen` is part of the C++ language, too.

Comment: FYI, the `fstream` class has `write()` method for block writing and `read()` method for block reading.  Thus you only need one I/O system.

Comment: `#endif // FUNCIONES_H_INCLUDED` bad paste of the file into the post?  There's no matching `#ifdef`.

Comment: please check [headers](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-files)

Answer (score 2):

Your functions header file is included before you defined `Materia`. Therefore, when the compiler starts compiling your main, it sees a function that takes a parameter of some undefined type, and tells you that this type hasn't been declared yet.

You can either move the include to be below the class definition, place a forward declaration of the class before the `functiones.h` include, or, my personal recommendation, move the `Materia` class into its own header file and include that from main and `functiones.h`.

Comment: Not only that, but the contents of `functiones.h` appears to be a CPP file, and should not be a header file.

Comment: One thing at a time. I remember I used to do that with common functions I used when I was learning how to write C++.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @alex`s answer *Your functions header file is included before you defined `Materia`*, so you can use everything in one file, example `Materia.cpp` as the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


class Materia{

private:
    int nroMateria;
    char nombreMateria[40];
    int cantAlumnos;
    int cantDocentes;

public:

    void Cargar(){

        int nro;

        cout<<"NUMERO DE MATERIA: ";
        cin>>nro;
        setNroMateria(nro);
        cout<<"NOMBRE DE MATERIA: ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(nombreMateria,35);
        cout<<"CANTIDAD DE ALUMNOS: ";
        cin>>cantAlumnos;
        cout<<"CANTIDAD DE DOCENTES: ";
        cin>>cantDocentes;        
        
    }

    void Mostrar();


    void setNroMateria(int nm){if(nm>0)nroMateria=nm;}
    void setNombreMateria(const char *nm){strcpy(nombreMateria,nm);}
    int getNroMateria(){return nroMateria;}
    char *getNombreMateria(){return nombreMateria;}


};        
void Materia::Mostrar(){

        cout<<"NUMERO DE MATERIA: ";
        cout<<nroMateria<<endl;
        cout<<"NOMBRE DE MATERIA: ";
        cout<<nombreMateria<<endl;
        cout<<"CANTIDAD DE ALUMNOS: ";
        cout<<cantAlumnos<<endl;
        cout<<"CANTIDAD DE DOCENTES: ";
        cout<<cantDocentes<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<endl;    
    
}

void CargarMateria();
void MostrarMateria();

bool grabarEnDisco(Materia);


int main(){


    int opc;


    while(true){
        system("cls");
        cout<<"MENU ARTICULOS: "<<endl;
        cout<<"1. CARGAR MATERIAS: "<<endl;
        cout<<"2. MOSTRAR MATERIAS: "<<endl;
        cout<<"0. SALIR DEL PROGRAMA: "<<endl;
        cout<<"SELECCIONE UNA OPCCION: "<<endl;
        cin>>opc;
        system("cls");
        switch(opc){
        case 1:
            CargarMateria();
            break;
        case 2:
            MostrarMateria();
            break;

        case 0:
            return 0;
            break;

        }
        system("pause");
    }


    return 0;
}

void CargarMateria(){


    Materia obj;

    obj.Cargar();

    if(grabarEnDisco(obj)==true){
        cout<<"REGISTRO AGREGADO";
    }else {


        cout<<"NO SE PUDO AGREGAR EL REGISTRO";

    }

    cout<<endl;

}


void MostrarMateria(){

    FILE *pMateria;
    Materia obj;

    pMateria = fopen("materias.dat", "rb");

    ///wb abre el archivo en modo escritura -> SIEMPRE CREA UN ARCHIVO VACIO
    ///ab abre el archivo y permite que se le agreguen registros.
    ///rb abre el archivo y permite leer los registros. Si no existe da error.

    if(pMateria == NULL){
        cout<<"ERROR DE ARCHIVO";
        return;
    }

    fread(&obj,sizeof(Materia),1,pMateria);
    fclose(pMateria);
    obj.Mostrar();       
    
}

bool grabarEnDisco(Materia obj){

    FILE *pMateria;

    pMateria = fopen("materias.dat", "wb");

    ///wb abre el archivo en modo escritura -> SIEMPRE CREA UN ARCHIVO VACIO
    ///ab abre el archivo y permite que se le agreguen registros.
    ///rb abre el archivo y permite leer los registros. Si no existe da error.

    if(pMateria == NULL){
        cout<<"ERROR DE ARCHIVO";
        return false;
    }

    fwrite(&obj,sizeof(Materia),1,pMateria);
    fclose(pMateria);
    return true;

}
```

or simply by declaring `Materia` **class** inside `funciones.h` and use as header file, like this:

```
class Materia{

private:
    int nroMateria;
    char nombreMateria[40];
    int cantAlumnos;
    int cantDocentes;

public:

    void Cargar(){

        int nro;

        std::cout<<"NUMERO DE MATERIA: ";
        std::cin>>nro;
        setNroMateria(nro);
        std::cout<<"NOMBRE DE MATERIA: ";
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cin.getline(nombreMateria,35);
        std::cout<<"CANTIDAD DE ALUMNOS: ";
        std::cin>>cantAlumnos;
        std::cout<<"CANTIDAD DE DOCENTES: ";
        std::cin>>cantDocentes;        
        
    }

    void Mostrar();


    void setNroMateria(int nm){if(nm>0)nroMateria=nm;}
    void setNombreMateria(const char *nm){std::strcpy(nombreMateria,nm);}
    int getNroMateria(){return nroMateria;}
    char *getNombreMateria(){return nombreMateria;}


};        
void Materia::Mostrar(){

        std::cout<<"NUMERO DE MATERIA: ";
        std::cout<<nroMateria<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"NOMBRE DE MATERIA: ";
        std::cout<<nombreMateria<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"CANTIDAD DE ALUMNOS: ";
        std::cout<<cantAlumnos<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"CANTIDAD DE DOCENTES: ";
        std::cout<<cantDocentes<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"-------------------------"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<std::endl;    
    
}
void CargarMateria();
void MostrarMateria();

bool grabarEnDisco(Materia);

void CargarMateria(){


    Materia obj;

    obj.Cargar();

    if(grabarEnDisco(obj)==true){
        std::cout<<"REGISTRO AGREGADO";
    }else {


        std::cout<<"NO SE PUDO AGREGAR EL REGISTRO";

    }

    std::cout<<std::endl;

}


void MostrarMateria(){

    FILE *pMateria;
    Materia obj;

    pMateria = std::fopen("materias.dat", "rb");

    ///wb abre el archivo en modo escritura -> SIEMPRE CREA UN ARCHIVO VACIO
    ///ab abre el archivo y permite que se le agreguen registros.
    ///rb abre el archivo y permite leer los registros. Si no existe da error.

    if(pMateria == NULL){
        std::cout<<"ERROR DE ARCHIVO";
        return;
    }

    std::fread(&obj,sizeof(Materia),1,pMateria);
    std::fclose(pMateria);
    obj.Mostrar();       
    

}


bool grabarEnDisco(Materia obj){

    FILE *pMateria;

    pMateria = std::fopen("materias.dat", "wb");

    ///wb abre el archivo en modo escritura -> SIEMPRE CREA UN ARCHIVO VACIO
    ///ab abre el archivo y permite que se le agreguen registros.
    ///rb abre el archivo y permite leer los registros. Si no existe da error.

    if(pMateria == NULL){
        std::cout<<"ERROR DE ARCHIVO";
        return false;
    }

    std::fwrite(&obj,sizeof(Materia),1,pMateria);
    std::fclose(pMateria);
    return true;


}
#endif // FUNCIONES_H_INCLUDED
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me elaborate on what Alex said.

The contents of `functiones.h` appears to be a CPP file, and should not be a header file.  For this simple program, that would typically go in the same file as the `main`.  For a project, that should be `functions.cpp` (remove the `#ifdef` guard) and make a separate `functiones.h` that contains just the *declarations* of the functions that will be called from the main program.

Your program should look like this:

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include "materia.h"
#include "funciones.h"

int main()
{
   ⋮
}
```

### functiones.h

```
void CargarMateria();
void MostrarMateria();
```

### functiones.cpp

```
#include < any needed system files >
#include "materia.h"
#include "functiones.h"  // always include "my own" header too.

// All the functions you defined in the original functiones.h
```

### materia.h

```
#pragma once
#ifdef SOME_UUID_THAT_WILL_BE_GLOBALLY_UNIQUE
#define that same thing

#include < any needed system files >

class Materia
{
    ⋮
};


#endif
```

In addition, you have one member function of class `Materia` that is not defined inside the class body.  That needs to go into a `materia.cpp` file, or if you put it in the header file (still outside the class body) you need to use the `inline` keyword.

## meanwhile...

[Don’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721) write `using namespace std;`.

You can, however, in a CPP file (not H file) or inside a function put individual `using std::string;` etc.  (See [SF.7](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#sf7-dont-write-using-namespace-at-global-scope-in-a-header-file).)

[⧺SL.io.50](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#slio50-avoid-endl) Don't use `endl`.

Prefer using the C++ library features rather than the old C library.  You're using `FILE*` stuff, but you also use `cin` and `cout` in your program.  **Really** *really* don't use `strcpy` and similar, or pass around `const char*` for strings.

Don't use the C macro for `NULL`.  C++ has a proper typed `nullptr`.  But, don't directly compare pointers against `nullptr`; rather, use the truth value directly.
`if(pMateria == NULL)` should be `if(pMateria)`.  But if you were using `fstream` rather than `FILE*` you would not be doing that anyway.

The style in C++ is to put the `*` or `&` with the *type*, not the identifier.  This is called out specifically near the beginning of Stroustrup’s first book, and is an intentional difference from C style.